# Dojo + JS: simplest algorithm for arrays intersaction

Tags: javascript, arrays, dojo, array-intersect

Imagine there is an object:

```
object = {
  'foo': 1,
  'bar': 'TARGET,
  'baz': 3
}
```

and an array of objects:

```
arrayOfObjects = [
  {
    'john': 'smith',
    'paul': 'walker'
  },
  {
    'bryan': 'best',
    'targetProp': 'TARGET'
  }
]
```

What would be the simplest algorithm to check whether first object has **intersecting property value** with some object in the array that has property with concrete name `targetProp`?

```
for (prop in object) {
  arary.forEach(arrayOfObjects, function(foundObject) {
    if (prop.indexOf(foundObject.targetProp) !== -1) {
      // Do smth
    }
  })
}
```

Is it possible to find it with only one loop using JavaScript or Dojo tools?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want it nicely done ?
If not, an ugly why could be to use `JSON.stringify`.

Something like :

```
var foo = JSON.stringify(arrayOfObjects);
for (prop in object) {
  if(foo.indexOf('"' + prop + '":') > -1) { //add double quote and colon to only match properties
      // Do smth
  }
}
```

But that is really really ugly...